# [SOLVED] xsens imu with robot_localization

Tags: navigation, odometry, xsens, robot-localization, base-footprint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello to everybody,
Im still new to ros and allready tryed really long to find a solution for my problem but all the things i tryed werent really helping.

The problem im having is that i want to connect an xsens-mti imu to my robot but cant get it to work under amcl together with the odom.

I tryed to implement the imu into the `robot_localization` and also tryed in the `robot_localization` to comment the odom0 and just use the imu0 data. The point is that the odom0 is working nicely and `robot_localization` is publishing data under `/odom` and `/odometry/filtered`. As soon as i comment the odom0 parts and just want to use the imu0 the `/odom` is still publishing but the `/odometry/filtered` which is as i think published by the `robot_localization.launch` is not showing any data. not from the odom and not from the imu.

You might need to know that my robot has a laser connected to it which, i think, till now computed a kind of imu to use together with the amcl. If im wrong please crrect me. The laser is no used under `robot_localization`. Just under amcl it is used. I also tryed to turn the laser off to see if the imu is working together with the odom but couldnt find a way to be sure about this because as far as i think my imu is not used in amcl.

The Imu itself works nicely. i can see the data published by the xsens under the topic `/imu/data`.
But as soon as i try to use the `/imu/data` in my `robot_localization` as a value for the imu0, i get this error  message:

> WARNING: failed to transform from /imu->base_footprint for imu0 message received at 1442471593.559769106. No transform exists from source to target frame.

So my suggestion now is that the imu is not used by the `robot localization` if im not pushing the `/imu/data` to the `robot localization`. I mean if i am not using the /imu/data as the value for the imu0. Again if im wrong with this please let me know.

Also if you need more data to find out a solution for me please let me know which data and how to collect it.

Thank you very much for your help and excuse me if im confusing you or making it really hard to understand my problem :-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217795/%5Bsolved%5D-xsens-imu-with-robot_localization/) by [moody](https://answers.ros.org/users/23922/moody/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello to everyone,

I solved the problem myself.
In my tf tree was the transform from /imu_link->base_footprint and not as requested from /imu->/base_footprint.
the request was hardcoded in a script for filtering the imu data and could not find /imu as it was not linked to the tf.

so i changed the code in the script to /imu_link and everything worked nicely.

Thanks for your help though :-)

Please mark the problem as solved.
I dont have enough karma to do anything on here...

---

Originally posted by [moody](https://answers.ros.org/users/23922/moody/) with karma: 31 on 2015-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1